# Spring Boot JPA relationship mapping and join queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Started learning Spring Boot, JPA. Finding difficult on understanding JPA relationship concepts, I tried joining two tables but could not achieve the expected result can anyone help me to get the expected result.

Below Requirement

Have two tables as below

[product_master table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me9qX.jpg) 
[product_catagory table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgEPJ.png)

**ProductMasterModel**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_master")
public class ProductMasterModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productId;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "product_category_id")
    private int productCategoryId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_category_id", referencedColumnName = "product_catogory_id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private ProductCatagoryMasterModel productCatagoryMasterModel; 

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getProductCategoryId() {
        return productCategoryId;
    }

    public void setProductCategoryId(int productCategoryId) {
        this.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;
    }

    public ProductMasterModel() {
        super();
    }

    public ProductMasterModel(String productName, int productCategoryId) {
        super();
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;

    }
}
```

**ProductCatagoryMasterModel**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="product_catagory")
public class ProductCatagoryMasterModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="product_catogory_id")
    private int productCategoryId;

    @Column(name="product_type")
    private String productType;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "productCatagoryMasterModel")
    private ProductMasterModel productMasterModel;

    public int getProductCategoryId() {
        return productCategoryId;
    }

    public void setProductCategoryId(int productCategoryId) {
        this.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    public ProductCatagoryMasterModel() {
        super();
    }

    public ProductCatagoryMasterModel(String productType) {
        super();
        this.productType = productType;

    }   
}
```

**ProductMasterRepository**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.lollipop.model.ProductMasterModel;

@Repository
public interface ProductMasterRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductMasterModel, Integer> {

@Query (value = "select * from product_master pm, product_catagory pc where pc.product_catogory_id = pm.product_category_id", nativeQuery = true)   
public List $ProductMasterModel$ getProductCategoryDetail(); 
}
```

**ProductService**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.lollipop.model.ProductMasterModel;
import com.lollipop.repository.ProductMasterRepository;

@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductMasterRepository productMasterRepository;

    public void getProductCat() {

        List $ProductMasterModel$ productMasterModel =  productMasterRepository.getProductCategoryDetail();

        System.out.println("productMasterModel value "+productMasterModel.toString());

    }
}
```

When calling `getProductCat()` method getting result as

> productMasterModel value [ProductMasterModel [productId=1011,
>   productName=Pencil, productCategoryId=10], ProductMasterModel
>   [productId=1012, productName= Mobile, productCategoryId=11]]

Since `ProductMasterModel` is not having `productType` variable it is not displaying productType

I need below result by joining two tables, please help me to acheive this

> [[productName=Pencil,productType=Stationary],[productName=
>   Mobile,productType=Electronics]]

Comment: @user7294900 can you please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, One to One Relationship should work.
Changes should be made in your POJO.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_master")
public class ProductMasterModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productId;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "product_category_id")
    private int productCategoryId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy= product_master, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public ProductCatagoryMasterModel productCatagory;    

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getProductCategoryId() {
        return productCategoryId;
    }

    public void setProductCategoryId(int productCategoryId) {
        this.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;
    }

    public ProductMasterModel() {

    }

    public ProductMasterModel(String productName, int productCategoryId) {
        super();
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;

    }
}
```

Next Address your Category Model

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="product_catagory")
public class ProductCatagoryMasterModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="product_catogory_id")
    private int productCategoryId;

    @Column(name="product_type")
    private String productType;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_master", referencedColumnName = "product_id")
    private ProductMasterModel productMaster;

    public int getProductCategoryId() {
        return productCategoryId;
    }

    public void setProductCategoryId(int productCategoryId) {
        this.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    public ProductCatagoryMasterModel() {
        super();
    }

    public ProductCatagoryMasterModel(String productType) {
        super();
        this.productType = productType;

    }   
}
```

We also need DAO

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.lollipop.model.ProductMasterModel;

@Repository
public interface ProductMasterRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductMasterModel, Integer> {
```

}

Product Service

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.lollipop.model.ProductMasterModel;
import com.lollipop.repository.ProductMasterRepository;

@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductMasterRepository productMasterRepository;

    public List<ProductMasterModel > getAllProducts() {
    return productMasterRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<ProductMasterModel > getProductById(int productId) {
    if (!productMasterRepository.existsById(productId)) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Product with id " + productId+ " not found");
    }
    return productMasterRepository.findById(productId);
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Added OnetoOne relationship to my model but getting below exception are we establishing  wrong column reference here?.. For giving more clarity I have product_category table with columns product_category_id(PK),product_type and product_master table with columns product_id(PK), Product_name,  product_category_id(FK to product_category table product_category_id column)

Comment: **Exception:**   Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.lollipop.model.ProductMasterModel.productCatagory, referenced property unknown: com.lollipop.model.ProductCatagoryMasterModel.product_master
 at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
]

Comment: This was the example how we should be doing one to one relationship in your case,But i can see i missed placed mapped by= product_master with product_category

Comment: Thank you.. I resolved the exception which I got, and created relationship successfully, but still not sure how to show expected result.

In ProductService class productMasterRepository.findAll() is returning data from product_master table but I need result as Product_name and product_type(it is on product_category table). can you please help me on this

Answer (score -1):

You need to establish ont-to-one relationship between those two tables.
Take a look at this:
[Example](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one)